# Retrieve Steam activity feed?

Tags: android-activity, rss, feed, steam

Has anyone found a way to retrieve the activity feed on Steam for a specific user to post on a website similar to tweets? I'm adding an activity feed to my website, but really the only thing I'm most active in is Steam, so it will get stale pretty quickly without Steam in there. I've looked at the web API, but it doesn't specify if I can grab my full feed and post it or if I can just grab certain stats for specific games or not. I've tried to find an RSS feed for my activity but had no luck so far, that would definitely be the preferable format.

Answer (score 1):

I've just looked at this and you can't grab the web feed directly from the site on RSS or JSON. The Web API is meant for developers of Steam applications so that they can get at the player information. For that, you need an API Key, which is provided by Steam. It is not a casual web interface like you might find on Google.

The nasty solution is to HTML scrape the page. I used [Yahoo! Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com) to scrape the page (and automatically update) but ultimately decided that was entirely too dirty as it assumes that the Steam pages won't change.

Answer (score 1):

A bit too late, but I'm also searching for this kind of RSS feed. I think I will end up creating a RSS bot to parse the AJAX response used to fetch the activity feed:

```
http://steamcommunity.com/id/[your username]/ajaxgetusernews
```

This URL doesn't work out of the box, I think we have to pass some cookies to get access to this page to make Steam think the bot is logged in as a normal user. It returns the HTML markup used to render the activity feed, and a URL to fetch the next batch of activities.

Be advised that this HTML markup is hard to parse because it is inconsistent.